# Having wifi antenna on router enabled causes large ping spikes on direct connected computer

Tags: router

So as the title implies having either the 2.4 Ghz or 5 Ghz antenna online on my router causes my Ethernet connected computer to have large and consistent ping spikes. I have a Linksys 1200AC WRT and I usually run the 5Ghz band off. Let me know if you need more info and specs and I'll provide as needed. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Start with describing the details: You have one computer connected to a Linksys 12000AC WRT via ethernet. The router is connected to the internet. When WLAN is disabled on the router, you can ping an address on the internet normally. Correct so far? When WLAN is enabled, what kind of "spikes" happen? Some pings take more time? All pings take more time? How much more time? Does the computer also have WLAN? Does the computer try to connect to the router *both* via ethernet and WLAN?

Comment: Okay so to clarify my computer is connected to the router via ethernet. With the router set to have both WLAN and ethernet connections enabled. The ethernet connection (My PC) will get large spike in various applications such as discord, games and what not. These spikes range from my standard 30-60MS ping to said services to 400-800 every 2-3 seconds for 1 second. Looking at the routers bandwidth monitor shows that WLAN activity is less than 10% of my max and ethernet is ever lower. I then proceeded to confirm this by temporary blocking all of the connection minus my ethernet PC with no change

Comment: However if I disable the 2.4 ghz antenna entirely in the router's firmware the ping spikes cease entirely.

Comment: Here is an example of the routers bandwidth monitor showing spikes in usage but they are minimal in terms of bandwidth: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/218206454727835659/338188796887695360/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to connect the computer *both* through WLAN and ethernet to the router, is this correct?

This is not going to work: WLAN and ethernet use different "local" IP addresses on your computer, and if the applications randomly pick one of those, they either seem to come from a "wrong" IP address (or NATed IP/port combination) on the other end, or the reply cannot be delivered reliably. So essentially, those packets are dropped. This is what causes the "spikes": About half of your packets will be dropped, which requires resending.

So make sure you are connected *either* through WLAN *or* through ethernet, or configure your computer to prefer one over the other if both are active. (I can explain how to do that on Linux, but I'm not sure how to do it on Windows, assuming you use Windwos - you didn't say in the question).

Comment: No. I'm just wanting my computer which has 0 WLAN support to be connected through ethernet and not suffer network performance when the wifi antenna on the router is enabled. I can't leave the wifi off however because while I don't use it others do. As I said above I already tested to make sure that the bandwidth wasn't being overconsumed. Also yes i'm on windows.